# Automator -> send file to email (from filename)

Tags: email, applescript, automator

Im trying to create an Automator folder action that sends an email with an attached file.

In my folder the files will be generated with the email as name:
Example: name@company.com.jpg, othername@othercompany.com.jpg and so on.

What I need is an action that copies the filename, remove the extension (.jpg), create an email and put the filename/email into the "To" and then sends the email.

I all ready have a working version where the file is attached to the e-mail and the content of the e-mail is filled out. But I can't find a solution to copy the file name and specify it to the "To" address.

Hope that someone out there can help me :-)

Comment: Could you please share your current Automator action so we could find a solution that fits your workflow ?

Comment: Sure :-) Here it is:
http://wikisend.com/download/103472/Image-to-email.zip

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've tried with Automator without succeeding looping through dropped files.

Here's a folder action script that does what you want, and how to attach it to a folder :

**1. Open AppleScript Editor**

**2. Paste the following script into a new document**

```
property mail_subject : "An image for you"
property mail_plain_content : "Attached you will the image you required." & return & return & "Best Regards" & return & "Automator"
property mail_html_content : "Attached you will the image you required.<br><br>Best Regards<br>Automator"

on adding folder items to this_folder after receiving these_items
    processItems(these_items)
end adding folder items to

on processItems(these_items)
    repeat with i from 1 to (count of these_items)
        set this_item to item i of these_items
        if isFolder(this_item) then
            processItems(getFolderItems(this_item))
        else
            processFile(this_item)
        end if
    end repeat
end processItems

on processFile(this_file)
    set mail_address to RemoveExtension(getFileName(this_file))
    tell application "Microsoft Outlook"
        set newMessage to make new outgoing message with properties {subject:mail_subject, plain text content:mail_plain_content, content:mail_html_content}
        tell newMessage
            make new recipient with properties {email address:{address:mail_address}}
            make new attachment with properties {file:this_file as alias}
            send
        end tell
        activate
    end tell
end processFile

on isFolder(this_item)
    tell application "System Events" to return (exists folder (this_item as string))
end isFolder

on RemoveExtension(this_name)
    -- This function comes from :
    -- http://www.macosxautomation.com/applescript/sbrt/index.html
    if this_name contains "." then
        set this_name to (the reverse of every character of this_name) as string
        set dot_offset to the offset of "." in this_name
        set this_name to (text (dot_offset + 1) thru -1 of this_name)
        set this_name to (the reverse of every character of this_name) as string
    end if
    return this_name
end RemoveExtension

on getExtension(this_name)
    if this_name contains "." then
        set this_name to (the reverse of every character of this_name) as string
        set dot_offset to the offset of "." in this_name
        set this_name to (text 1 thru (dot_offset - 1) of this_name)
        set this_name to (the reverse of every character of this_name) as string
        return this_name
    else
        return ""
    end if
end getExtension

on getFileName(this_file)
    tell application "Finder" to return name of this_file
end getFileName

on getFolderItems(this_folder)
    tell application "Finder" to return items of this_folder
end getFolderItems
```

**3. Save it in your *~/Library/Scripts/Folder Action Scripts* Folder**

Menu **File** > **Save**

Go to the right folder : press <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> and paste:
***~/Library/Scripts/Folder Action Scripts***
and click **Go**

Save as : **Image - Email using name as address.scpt** *(for example)*
Format : **Script**

**4. Create a new folder that will be watched for added items**

**5. Associate the script to the folder**

In the Finder, right click on your folder, then select **Services** > **Folder Actions Setup** 
Select the new created **Image - Email using name as address.scpt** script

You're done, drop a file whose name is an address, mail will be sent.

Comment: WOW! This is exactly what I'm looking for. And look at that description... Excellent! You're to cool Bibou ;-)

Comment: Would it be possible to make a "Send active email" command to Outlook, so that the e-mails are send in the same action. Otherwise I have to press "send" manually on all the e-mails :-)

Comment: Replacing the "open" command by "send" in the on processFile / tell new Message part should do the trick. I've edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. It's really appreciated :-)